# Pass data from first activity to second activity to play song

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

How do I pass data between these activities because now I can play music in first activity when I click the list item,but now I want to pass data from first activity which contains list to second activity directly play song in second activity and also I am confuse about service because I am using service in my first activity when I play song in second activity what will be happen on service

Comment: please help answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it adding extra data to the intent that starts 2nd activity.

For that your song class must implement Parcelable

```
public class Song implements Parcelable
{
    string artist;
    string songName;
    string filePath;

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    protected Song(Parcel in)
    {
        artist = in.readString();
        songName = in.readString();
        filePath = in.readString();     
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(artist);
        dest.writeString(songName);       
        dest.writeString(filePath);
    }
}
```

And then when opening second activity to play song it would be like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("song", songToPlay);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

For last you would receive the song in the 2nd activity as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song_player);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null)
    {
        if (intent.hasExtra("song"))
        {
            Song songToPlay = intent.getExtra("song");      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i used this one but the data inside array is two much

Comment: If you have to pass a file, simply pass the file location

Comment: Actually i used content provider then i put in list  now if i pass the id of data from first activity and then in the second activity if i query to content provider to get same data of id how i do that